# Getting "FailedPreconditionError" in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to run GAN deep learning model in kaggle kernel. I am trying to run the model in a terminal passing Dataset as argument. Both model and dataset are uploaded in kernel Input dataset.
But when I try to run the notebook it's showing 'FailedPreconditionError' like this:

```
 tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: 
 /kaggle/input/dataaa/selfie2anime/trainA; Is a directory
 [[{{node ReadFile}}]]
 [[IteratorGetNext]]
 [[RemoteCall]]
 [[IteratorGetNext]]
```

I am unable to understand why this error is occurring. I googled the solution and some suggested to check for unwanted tabs, but there are no tabs in command or path of data set.
I am using this command to run the script :

`!python3 /kaggle/input/modell/UGATIT/main.py --dataset=/kaggle/input/dataaa/selfie2anime/ --light True`